# How to improve code structure in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, laravel-5

I've created two method in my controller in Laravel to fetch data from another website using **PHP CURL** and pass to view.
I will used **httpData** method for initial **ID** and **URL** and **getHttpCode** method to get **HTTP_code** to find any errors will happen when I fetch data from another website But I don't much understand about this below code performance and how can I testing In **PHPstrom** to make sure with performance

Here is my function

```
 private function httpData($url =null, $id = null)
    {
        if($id){
            $url = 'http://assignment.gae.golgek.mobi/api/v1/items/'.$id;
        }
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_PRETRANSFER_TIME, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PRIVATE, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

        if (!$executed = curl_exec($ch)) {

            $res = $executed;
            $data = false;
            curl_close($ch);
        } else {

            if ($this->http_code = $this->getHttpCode(curl_getinfo($ch))) {

                $res = $this->http_code;
                $data = $executed;
            } else {
                $res = false;
            }
        }
        return ['s_respond' => $res, 'data' => $executed];
    }

    private function getHttpCode($http)
    {
        if (is_array($http)) {
            if (!empty($http['http_code'] || $http['http_code'] != 0)) {
                return $http['http_code'];
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And I will call this method as below

```
public function sendData()
{
    $url = 'website/api/v1/products';
    $data = $this->httpData($url);
    return view('products.list', ['data'=>$data]);
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: post here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes this should be OK for Code Review but I would suggest reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve it a bit, especially the title.

Comment: I got one mistake here OK I will rollback with website policy.
I Know I will be vote down when I go wrong policy.

Comment: Yes if your code has errors then you should fix those first before posting to CR

Comment: @Pharancis
What CR mean?

Comment: In the question title you asked about improving code structure. In the question itself you asked about improving performance. These two things are not the same. Structure is about making it easy to read and maintain; performance is about making it run quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to addopt the 'early return pattern'.

I did a rewrite in you getHttpCode, it seems more clear to me:

```
private function getHttpCode($http)
{
    if ( !is_array($http) 
      || empty($http['http_code'])
      || $http['http_code'] === 0)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return $http['http_code'];
}
```